# error CS1501: No overload for method `Reverse' takes `0' arguments

Tags: c#, string, mono, reverse

I have this code to reveres the words in a sentence.

```
using System;

class Code 
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string x = "I am Sam";

        foreach(var a in x.Split().Reverse()) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile this code (mono 2.10), I got `error CS1501: No overload for method`Reverse' takes `0' arguments` error message.

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the `System.Linq` namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```